# How to access iPhone location from a web page?

Tags: iphone

Starting with iPhone 3.0, web pages can access the location data of the iPhone (Google Latitude does that).

Can anyone provide the code (JavaScript I assume) to do that?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Alocola](http://www.alocola.com/) is an application that allows web apps to access GPS coordinates on pre-3.0 iPhones

Starting with 3.0, you can use the [Geolocation Javascript API](http://blog.bemoko.com/2009/06/17/iphone-30-geolocation-javascript-api/) (from [Geolocation API on the iPhone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/221592/geolocation-api-on-the-iphone)).