# Google Street View

Tags: google-maps

How do I embed google street view to my site
I want to show a user location upon visiting my site.

Updated: Is there any clear tutorials or links for Google Maps

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### You can do it with Google Maps API2

and here is the [Google Maps API2 Documention on Street View](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/v2/services.html#Streetview)

#### Just keep in mind it needs Flash.

update:
and to get the user location, you can use 'The Geolocation API Specification [which] is [a] part of the W3 Consortium’s standards But be warned: it hasn’t been finalized as yet.' consider looking at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/221592/geolocation-api-on-the-iphone) for an example code and more details.

Comment: I accept it, but is there any step by step tutorial to Google Maps..?

Comment: for the specific work that you want, there is none that I am aware of. The Google Maps API documentation is pretty decent and full of examples. just a thumb rule for learning new API's are to start with simple stuff and once you get hang of it go for exactly what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Besides of using the latest Google Maps API version, you Can embed any panoramic view of Google Street View very easily. Being in Google Maps while browsing in Street View, you will find on the left page upper corner the street name and next to the marker a 3 dots vertical line.

You need to click on the 3 dots which are shown next to the street name info and then a form will pop up to give you the option to embed a html iframe with size options on the panoramic view wanted.

I hope it helps.