# Mobile web app phone proximity

Tags: web-applications, mobile, gps, proximity

I would like to just do a mobile web app test. My idea is to find out if two or more devices are in proximity of each other.

Im thinking this can be done by connecting the web app to a server, which then knows the phones ip and adds it's coordinates in a database. Then if another phone is connected to the app it finds all other coordinates and returns to you the ones that are like 5 km away or how ever many km.

I don't want to use bluetooth either, so any ofther suggestions are welcome. Im am just wondering if that's a good way to go, or at least test.

Answer (score 0):

http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/um/people/maheshba/papers/ephemera-imc09.pdf

I'd say no with your initial method, but phones also can use other methods of finding out where they are:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Location-based_service

Chances are you're not going to be pulling that data raw, so I'd look into using the built-in geolocation services to get that data:

[Geolocation API on the iPhone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/221592/geolocation-api-on-the-iphone)

Comment: if it's a web app i would most likely use phonegap to distribute to all devices. I'm only java, so doing a native app would take longer to do for each device. I know who to get the location, the problem is the app knowing where another phone is. There needs to be some kind of server communication no?. Thaks for the links

Comment: Web app (to me) implies something that runs in the browser. Obviously, you can get more system data by running an native app/phonegap thingy. You'd obviously want some sort of server-side communication in order to manage locations and such. That's not my area of expertise, but I'm sure that once you boiled your app down into the components you want, any questions you have could easily be answered by others on here