# Get iPhone location data into a Google Maps

Tags: javascript, iphone, google-maps, geolocation

I am looking to develop a feature for a browser app I am developing. I was hoping to get any advice on this topic:

1. A user walks around with their iphone.
2. During this time location data is recorded of their walk
3. This data can then be exported to Google Maps and I can see the route overlaid on a Google Map in my browser.

**Is this possible? Where would I start and how would the data be recorded?**

Comment: Did my answer help you or do you still have open questions?

Comment: I am trying to export coordinates of the recorded route - for storage in a database, as such this would also be useful - is this possible?

Comment: Yes, of course this is. For example OpenStreetMap API gives you the coordinates of a route. You can send them to your server and store it in a database there. You can also send the data recorded by your iPhone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this is possible (assuming you want to use Javascript as it is tagged to your question).

Getting the location data on an iPhone is possible, [see this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/221592/geolocation-api-on-the-iphone). You can use the [Google Maps API](https://developers.google.com/maps/) to display a map and draw the recorded path on it. I would rather display the walked route direct in your app rather than exporting/importing coordinates of the recorded route.

Before implementing the App, I would take a look on both Google Maps API and [OpenStreemMap API](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/API) to find out which you like more and fits your needs best. Playing with some examples before implementing your app might be a good point to start with.